# Project Euler #4 Java - No output

Tags: java

I wrote this:

```
class Problem4 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int reversenum = 0;
    for (int i=100; i<1000; i++) {
      for (int j=100; j<1000; j++) {
        int tempPro = i*j;
        int temptempfun = tempPro;
        while (tempPro != 0) {
          reversenum *= 10;
          reversenum += tempPro%10;
          tempPro /= 10;
        }
        if (reversenum == temptempfun) {
          System.out.println(reversenum);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not getting any output when I run this and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT:**

Fixed it by moving the reversenum declaration inside the inner for loop.

```
class Problem4 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int largest = 0;
    for (int i=100; i<1000; i++) {
      for (int j=100; j<1000; j++) {
        int tempPro = i*j;
        int temptempfun = tempPro;
        int reversenum = 0;
        while (tempPro != 0) {
          reversenum *= 10;
          reversenum += tempPro%10;
          tempPro /= 10;
        }
        if (reversenum == temptempfun) {
          if (reversenum > largest) {
            largest = reversenum;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.println(largest);
  }
}
```

Comment: Try putting an else to see what the numbers are and have a think?

Comment: Try to match their given two digit number - which will be quicker to debug anyway, then try 3 digits.

Answer (score 2):

Two integers reversenum and temptempfun doesn't equal in your loop. That's why, it can't print anything.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
int reversenum = 0;
```

you are defining reversenum as zero and in while loop:

```
while (tempPro != 0) {
          reversenum *= 10;
```

you try to multiply a number with zero and assign it into this variable again. The possible problem is in this logic. You should give a nonzero initial value to your `reversenum` and you should clear it before while loop because `reversenum` variable will store previous iteration's value.

**EDIT:**

You need to debug your code in an IDE such as Eclipse. If you do it, then you can easily understand what's going on in your code.

Comment: Your answer is partially correct. I just fixed my code by moving the reversenum declaration inside the inner for loop.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that `reversenum` is an attempt to reverse the number (to check for a palindrome) so needs to change each time (without being affected by previous tries).

Furthermore, multiplying it by 0, will remain at zero when it is zero.

This will print something (but you'll need to think about how to find the answer you actually need).

```
class Problem4 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i=100; i<1000; i++) {
      for (int j=100; j<1000; j++) {
        int reversenum = 0; //<- moved to change each time
        int tempPro = i*j;
        int temptempfun = tempPro;
        while (tempPro != 0) {
          reversenum *= 10;
          reversenum += tempPro%10;
          tempPro /= 10;
        }
        if (reversenum == temptempfun) {
          System.out.println(reversenum);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When you swap those two lines in the while loop, it'll multiply the final reversed number by 10 and give you the wrong output. What I've done is and works correctly.

Comment: Glad you fixed it

Comment: No idea why I swapped the lines - putting them back